# Make issue in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, make, perl

I have a "make file" to install some files, which will highlight syntax in `gvim`.

It was downloaded from [Github](https://github.com/dcblack/uvm_vim_extras), for reference.

When I attempt to install it was showing some error:

```
"let g:vimball_home='.'" -c '%MkVimball! /home/malai/Downloads/uvm_vim_extras-master/malai_uvm-20201128-1728.vmb' -c quit uvm_files.txt
/bin/sh: 1: let g:vimball_home='.': not found
make: *** [Makefile:70: /home/malai/Downloads/uvm_vim_extras-master/malai_uvm-20201128-1728.vmb] Error 127
```

I couldn't fix this error. Could someone tell me what is the issue.

Comment: `/bin/sh: 1: let g:vimball_home='.': not found` - is this some variable or call that the script requires to complete?

Comment: It looks like `VIM_BIN` is not being set by the (distinctly OSX looking) `Find_executable` scriptlet. Try setting it explicitly ex. `make VIM_BIN=/usr/bin/vim vimball`

Comment: This software hasn't been touched since 2015. I suspect that it's broken in current Ubuntu releases.